# How to Stop UIWebView from playing mp3?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview, mp3

I am loading a MP3 file into `UIWebView` control on an iPad Application, I have a `UIButton` called **done** the user expected to dismiss the `UIWebView` and stop the music, here is a code snippet:

```
// points to the mp3 file path
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.sFilePath]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:request];
```

When the user hit done I do the following:

```
[self.webview removeFromSuperview];
[self.webview release];
```

But that does not stop the music from playing, I noticed that loading mp3 files on `UIWebView` opens the QuickTime player is that correct way?

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video/audio streaming does not stop even if UIWebView is closed - iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719270/video-audio-streaming-does-not-stop-even-if-uiwebview-is-closed-ipad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you play the sound yourself using for example [AVAudioPlayer](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2FDOCUMENTATION%2FAVFoundation%2FReference%2FAVAudioPlayerClassReference%2F&rct=j&q=avaudioplayer&ei=RuDHTbzoHY2E-waX9dDWAQ&usg=AFQjCNFPlC_pr4AnS2vJ07eNqDviecTB5w) (probably the easiest way to play and control sounds in iOS).

Something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.sFilePath];
NSData *mySound = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:mySound error:NULL];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audioPlayer play];
```

You can then stop the sound as simple as:

```
[audioPlayer stop];
```

or

```
[audioPlayer pause];
```

Don't forget to include the AVFoundation.framework in your project.

Comment: @iceydee: I will try that and get back to you asap.

Comment: @iceydee: Thank you for the answer, it's not what I expected though. I will wait for a while and see if anyone can help me with the `UIWebView` issue if no one does I will accept your answer and use your solution, Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually want the play/pause controls to be shown to the user?

Comment: @iceydee : No At all I want to do is to stop the music when the user click done "like done listening to the music" or when I want to move to another View.

Comment: @AhmadTK but the snippet I gave you, doesn't it fulfill the purpose? Just call [audioPlayer stop] when the user clicks the button. If you want the track to be looping forever you can change numberOfLoops to -1 I believe it is. I'd put the audioPlayer in a property so it is easily accessible from other classes/views.

Comment: @iceydee: it full fill the purpose **BUT** as I told you before my issue was loading mp3 audio files into a `UIWebView` and I really want to keep my current app design as it is, in a couple of days if no one showed up with a solution for the `UIWebView` I will Accept your answer.

Comment: @AhmadTK I think your best shot then is to use the HTML5 <audio>-tag inside your webview-contents and control it using the .play() and .pause() functions of that.

Comment: @iceydee: Thank you very much for the suggestion i am not at the office right now I will try it first thing in the morning : )

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a dupe of [Video/audio streaming does not stop even if UIWebView is closed - iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719270/video-audio-streaming-does-not-stop-even-if-uiwebview-is-closed-ipad)

The solution there:

```
[self.webContent loadRequest:NSURLRequestFromString(@"about:blank")];
```

Comment: I think I have tried this before, but I will give it a try first thing in the morning.

Comment: If you are using the web view simply to play audio, I recommend iceydee's solution above...