# Stop video in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

In my iPad App I have a modal view (`UIViewController` with modal presentation style `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`)

Inside the view is a UIWebView with a HTML page and an embedded YouTube-Video. If I start the video and close the view, the video doesn't stop. The audio continues and you can see a small "play icon" next to the "battery icon" in the status bar.

How can I stop the video?

Comment: Anyone found this issue in iOS 9/10?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Do integrate following code to sort out the problem.

```
    -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [webView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea how it works only in viewWillDisappear. Thanks Anyways!

Comment: I've linked to this answer from [an answer I'm still seeing traffic on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2746967/281437) from '10 based on chibimai's comment.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case :( I still hear the audio

Answer (score 17):

Also you can try to pause video:

```
NSString *script = @"var videos = document.querySelectorAll(\"video\"); for (var i = videos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { videos[i].pause(); };";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to the other since I'd like the user to return to the webpage in the state they left it. (Well, with the video paused instead of playing s fine.)

Comment: Generally in applications, videos play from very beginning. It depends upon an application's feature to resume a video or to play from beginning. Though I appreciate Alena's answer. Thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

```
//  Halt anything in progress
(contentViewController as! WebViewController).webView.loadHTMLString("Yoink://", baseURL: nil)
```

needed in a windowController's windowShouldClose() method when I close a window

Answer (score 2):

Use the following javascript in WKWebview to *pause* the video player in swift

```
wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("var videos = document.querySelectorAll(\"video\"); for (var i = videos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { videos[i].pause(); };", completionHandler: nil)
```

to stop the video player use:

```
wkWebView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift method :

```
override public func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.webView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
}
```

thanks @alloc_iNit

Answer (score 1):

I saw there are many suggestions with loading blank page. That is really bad approach.

It will cause your webview to be blank if, let say you push you another view on top of it.

Most simple solution is to reload the view with:

*Swift*

```
webView.reload()
```

*Obj-C*

```
[webView reload]
```

Comment: @Starwave I understand your concern, that's quite a fair point, I guess it depends on what's best for your product, in my case, I dont want user to be presented with blank page when they tap back/close the view presented on top. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to have it in the same subclass instead of the vc.

```
override func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?) {
    if newWindow == nil {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("var videos = document.querySelectorAll(\"video\"); for (var i = videos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { videos[i].pause(); };", completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```