# How do I stop a YouTube embedded video from playing without hitting pause in the web view?

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, uiwebview, youtube-api

I have a YouTube video embedded in a `UIWebView`. It plays just fine. When I segue to a different View Controller without pausing the video, however, it continues to play the audio. How do I stop it?

Code:

```
func loadYouTubeVideo() {

    let youTubeLink: String = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ac_om5HCjvg"
    let width = 300
    let height = 200
    let frame = 50
    let html:NSString = "<iframe width=\(width) height=\(height) src=\(youTubeLink) frameborder=\(frame) allowfullscreen></iframe>"
    self.youTubeWebView.loadHTMLString(html as String, baseURL: nil)

}
```

I need a Swift answer. I've tried using Objective-C, but it doesn't translate unless I'm doing it wrong:

```
 let script = "var videos = document.querySelectorAll(\"video\"); for (var i = videos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { videos[i].pause(); };"
 youTubeWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(script)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop video in UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038100/stop-video-in-uiwebview)

Comment: Unfortunately, those answers don't work for me. It could be that it's in Objective-C, and I'm working in Swift.

Comment: What do you mean they don't work?  Have you tried translating them into Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the user resuming the video from the beginning after navigating away from the view, have the webview load an empty page:

```
webView.loadHTMLString("<html><head></head><body></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

If you do this, you will have to load your video again in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        webView.loadHTMLString(nil, baseURL: nil)
    }
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: `loadHTMLString` requires a non-optional string HTML string, you can't pass in nil.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to stop my audio:

```
webView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
```